# Check if values in a list occur in a file

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, if-statement

I have a file which looks like below, however you should note that in reality the file contains more then 100.000 records.

```
blue    black    red      250
red     black    blue     140
black   yellow   purple   100
orange  blue     blue     140
blue    black    red      250
red     black    blue     140
black   yellow   purple   700
orange  blue     blue     200
```

I also have a list which contains the following values `my_list = ['140', '700', '800']`

**Now I want the following:**

1. If one of the values of `my_list` occurs in the file `row[3]` I want to append the whole record to a new list.
2. If one of the values of my list does not occur in the file row[3] I want to append the value itself and the rest of the values should be `'unknown'`.

**This is my code:**

```
new_list = []
with open(my_file, 'r') as input:
                reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = '\t')
                row3_list = [] 
                for row in reader:  
                    row3_list.append(row[3])                  
                    for my_number in my_list :
                        if my_number in row3_list :
                            new_list.append(row)       
                        elif my_number not in row3_list :
                            new_list.append(['Unknown', 'Unkown', 'Unkown', row[3]])
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
red     black    blue     140
orange  blue     blue     140
red     black    blue     140
black   yellow   purple   700
unknown unkown   unkown   800
```

**My problem:**
Like I mentioned my file contains a bulk of records could be more then 100.000+. So above way is taking ages. I have been waiting for output for about 15 minutes now but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use numpy and pandas to get more efficient:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read file to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',  delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

# give names to columns for simplicity
df.columns = ['a','b', 'c', 'd']

# our values
my_list = ['140', '700', '800']
my_second_list = ['orange', 'red']

# filter rows that not in my_list
new_df = df[df['d'].isin(my_list) & df['a'].isin(my_second_list)]

# find values in my_list that are not in file
missing = np.setdiff1d(np.asarray(my_list), new_df['d'].unique().astype(str))

# add there rows with unknown
for i in missing:
    d = {'a': ['unknown'], 'b': ['unknown'], 'c': ['unknown'], 'd': i}
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    new_df = new_df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
result = new_df.values.tolist()
```

output for given data sample:

[image]

Comment: I want to keep using my for loop, not changing much of my current code....

Comment: @Al-Andalus the problem is the for loops you are using is slowing the code down a lot. the only way to overcome this is by using pandas and numpy or to improve your code and i don't see how the code can be improved.

Comment: @Al-Andalus _why?_ practically, using a loop with Python builtins will be orders of magnitude slower than loading all your data and performing some vectorized operation with a dedicated data library (such as Pandas) - this Answer goes into some detail with performance numbers to illustrate it (and also showing Python builtins still shine with small amounts of data) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4541045

Comment: Oke but I need the output back as a list of list not as a df

Comment: @Al-Andalus edited it to return a list of list :)

Comment: Okay, last question. Lets say I want to add an other filter. If a value in `my_second_list = ['orange', 'red']` is in `column a` of the `df`. So that means I will only grab a record if column d is in `my_list` and column a is in `my_second_list`

Comment: @Al-Andalus fixed now it filters by my_second_list and my_list.

Comment: @Al-Andalus This solution is wrong. look at the final result. you don't want to have two rows with 'unknown' values.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco look at the comments after the right answer was given @
Al-Andalus asked also to filter by another list my_second_list. hope this clarifies why this answer is correct :)

Comment: @RoseGod Is it possible to chat somewhere? I wanted to add some extra functionalities but I could not make it work. Thank you

Comment: @Al-Andalus i don't know how you can chat on this platform and i don't want to share my info publicly. I think it will be best if you edit the question or make a new question :)

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239514/so-python you can join in here!

Comment: @RoseGod, can I expect an reaction from you?

Answer (score 3):

Try this (you need to install pandas with `pip install pandas`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep='\t', header=None, dtype=str,
                 names=('0', '1', '2', '3'))

result = df[df['3'].isin(my_list)]
vals = df[~df.index.isin(result.index)]['3']
if len(vals) > 0:
    tot = vals.map(int).sum()
    result = result.append(
        {'0': 'unknown', '1': 'unknown', '2': 'unknown',
         '3': vals.map(int).sum()},
        ignore_index=True,
    )

result = result.values.tolist()
```

If you don't want to use pandas then I would do something like this:

```
import bisect
import csv


def elem_in_list(lst, x):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(lst, x)
    if i != len(lst) and lst[i] == x:
        return True
    return False

my_list = ['140', '700', '800']
result = []
tot = 0
is_tot_used = False
lst = sorted(list(map(int, my_list)))
with open('myfile.txt') as input:
    reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:  
        if elem_in_list(lst, int(row[3])):
            result.append(row)
        else:
            is_tot_used = True
            tot += int(row[3])

if is_tot_used:
    result.append(['unknown'] * 3 + [tot])
```

If `my_list` is large then this code will be much faster than yours. Why? Because searching a sorted list can be done in O(log(n)), while searching an unsorted list can be done in O(n).

Comment: will the result be a list or df again? I need it as a list

Comment: @Al-Andalus Fixed, now you have a list of lists

Answer (score 1):

Import your csv file as a Pandas Data Frame

```
import pandas as pd
A = [['blue',    'black',    'red',      250],
['red',    'black',    'blue',     140],
['black',   'yellow',   'purple',   100],
['orange',  'blue' ,    'blue',     140],
['blue',    'black',    'red',      250],
['red',     'black' ,   'blue' ,    140],
['black',   'yellow',   'purple',   700],
['orange',  'blue' ,    'blue' ,    200]]

df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['A','B','C','D'])

df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D'])
my_list = ['140', '700', '800']
for ii in my_list:
    temp = df.loc[df['D'].isin([int(ii)])]
    if len(temp.index):
        df_ = df_.append(temp)
    else:
        to_append = ['unknown', 'unknown',   'unknown',   int(ii)]
        df_.loc[len(df_)] = to_append
print(df_)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to simplify the code you have to avoid the second for loop.  If you try something like this, it ought to finish in a more reasonable amount of time:

```
new_list = []
my_file = "some_file.txt"
my_list = ['140', '700', '800']
with open(my_file, 'r') as input:
    reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:  
        if row[3] in my_list:
            new_list.append(row)
        else:
            new_list.append(['Unknown', 'Unkown', 'Unkown', row[3]])
```